# error: T does not name a type - For specialisation using strongly typed enums

Tags: c++, templates, enums, typedef

I was trying to avoid duplicating code for by having a base class with mostly static functions and members. And then I'd derive from the base class in some other classes while using the code from the base class.

```
#include <unordered_set>

enum struct Type
{
    A = 0, B, C
};

template <Type T> struct Impl;

template <Type T> struct Base
{
    typedef T Tp; // error: 'T' does not name a type

    typedef Impl<T> Imp;

    static std::unordered_set<Imp*> _Inst;

    static void grab(Imp * ptr) { _Inst.insert(ptr); }
    static void drop(Imp * ptr) { _Inst.erase(ptr); };
    static void swap(Imp * ptr, Imp * old) { drop(old); grab(ptr); }

    // ...
};

template <> struct Impl<Type::A> : public Base<Type::A>
{
    // ...
};

template <> struct Impl<Type::B> : public Base<Type::B>
{
    // ...
};

template <> struct Impl<Type::C> : public Base<Type::C>
{
    // ...
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

The actual implementation is a lot more different than that example and requires me to have an approach similar to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` isn't a type and you can only `typedef` types. Create a member variable. For example,

```
constexpr Type Tp = T;
```

Comment: ITYM "`T` isn't a type`